# Is there an easy way to simplify this code using a loop in r?

Tags: r, loops

I am working in Rstudio and have a series of codes just like these. There are 34 total and I am wondering if there is an easy ways to just write it once and have it loop through the defined variable of **rsqRow.a{#}**, **combineddfs.a{#}** and internally used variables of **s_{## 'State'}**

```
# s_WA.train.lr.Summary

rsqRow.a32 = summary(s_WA.train.lr)$r.squared
# rsqRow.a32

Coef = summary(s_WA.train.lr)$coef[,1] # row, column
CoefRows = data.frame(Coef)
Pval = summary(s_WA.train.lr)$coef[,4]
PvalRows = data.frame(Pval)
combineddfs.a32 <- merge(CoefRows, PvalRows, by=0, all=TRUE)
# combineddfs.a32
```

```
# s_WI.train.lr.Summary

rsqRow.a33 = summary(s_WI.train.lr)$r.squared
# rsqRow.a33

Coef = summary(s_WI.train.lr)$coef[,1] # row, column
CoefRows = data.frame(Coef)
Pval = summary(s_WI.train.lr)$coef[,4]
PvalRows = data.frame(Pval)
combineddfs.a33 <- merge(CoefRows, PvalRows, by=0, all=TRUE)
# combineddfs.a33
```

```
# s_WY.train.lr.Summary

rsqRow.a34 = summary(s_WY.train.lr)$r.squared
# rsqRow.a34

Coef = summary(s_WY.train.lr)$coef[,1] # row, column
CoefRows = data.frame(Coef)
Pval = summary(s_WY.train.lr)$coef[,4]
PvalRows = data.frame(Pval)
combineddfs.a34 <- merge(CoefRows, PvalRows, by=0, all=TRUE)
# combineddfs.a34
```

Comment: Consider storing the `combineddfs.a#` in a list.

Comment: Some food for thought, along the lines of @MartinGal's suggestion to use a list-of-frames: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358272

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments you should get the data in a list to avoid such repetitive processes.

Find out a common pattern that represents all your dataframe names in the global environment and use that as a pattern in `ls` to get character vector of their names. You can then use `mget` to get dataframes in a list.

```
list_data <- mget(ls(pattern = 's_W.*train\\.lr'))
```

Once you have the list of dataframes, you can use `lapply` to iterate over it and in the function return the values that you want. Note that there might be a simpler way to write what you have in your attempt however as I don't have the data I am not going to take the risk to shorten your code. Here I am returning `rsqRow` and `combineddfs` for each dataframe. You can add/remove objects according to your preference.

```
all_values <- lapply(list_data, function(x) {
    rsqRow = summary(x)$r.squared
    Coef = summary(x)$coef[,1]
    CoefRows = data.frame(Coef)
    Pval = summary(x)$coef[,4]
    PvalRows = data.frame(Pval)
    combineddfs <- merge(CoefRows, PvalRows, by=0, all=TRUE)
    list(rsqRow, combineddfs)
})
```